# Restoring Postgresql From Installation Files

Tags: linux, postgresql, raspberry-pi

I had a postgresql database in a raspberry pi 2 Raspbian Jessie. But somehow OS stopped to work and I want to get my postgresql tables and functions from it. So I can restore them in another postgresql DB.

I can explore file system of raspberry pi with another linux machine. So I can see all files in it. But I dont know how to get tables and functions from it. There is not any backup but only a postgresql installation files.

Comment: I would start here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/backup.html and then look at this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/creating-cluster.html  i.e. effectively create a backup of your existing system and restore it into a running one.

Comment: I just have files not a working system. So I cannot backup them now.

Comment: Use a file system level backup as described in the references that I gave.